# A spam site is forwarding my site and showing add at the end of it

Tags: wordpress, security, spam

I made a new website with Wordpress which is http://drfarzin.net I randomly was googling my site that i saw another domain is presenting my site http://upciran.ir/web/aHR0cDovL2RyZmFyemluLm5ldC8=! plus it has an advertisement at the end of it.
here is the steps i did to prevent this spam but it didn't succeed:

1. saw my log file while requesting to http://upciran.ir/web/aHR0cDovL2RyZmFyemluLm5ldC8=
   which was {5.78.123.116, 162.158.89.204 - -
   [08/Apr/2016:04:32:46 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 39199 "http://upciran.ir/web/aHR0cDovL2RyZmFyemluLm5ldC8=" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.110 Safari/537.36"
   - - -
   [08/Apr/2016:04:32:46 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 25733 "-" "-"
   5.78.123.116, 162.158.89.204 - -
   [08/Apr/2016:04:32:47 -0400] "GET /wp-admin/admin.php?page=stats&noheader&proxy&chart=admin-bar-hours-scale-2x HTTP/1.1" 200 613 "http://drfarzin.net/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.110 Safari/537.36"
   }
2. pinging http://upciran.ir/web/aHR0cDovL2RyZmFyemluLm5ldC8= then block its ip in cloudflare  and wordfence (wordpress plugin)

**the odd part that i dont undrestand is while you brows in to http://upciran.ir/web/aHR0cDovL2RyZmFyemluLm5ldC8= , its url will not be changed **

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's loaded from iframe...

You cannot check it from the server's side, **but you can use javascript to detect it after the page has loaded**. Compare top and self, if they're not identical, you are in a frame.

Additionally, some modern browsers respect the **X-FRAME-OPTIONS** header, that can have two values:

**DENY** – prevents the page from being rendered if it is contained in a frame
SAMEORIGIN – same as above, unless the page belongs to the same domain as the top-level frameset holder.
Users include Google's Picasa, that cannot be embedded in a frame.

Browsers that support the header, with the minimum version:

IE8 and IE9
Opera 10.50
Safari 4
Chrome 4.1.249.1042
Firefox 3.6.9 (older versions with NoScript)

**EXAMPLE:**

```
if(top!=self){
        top.location.replace(document.location);
        alert("For security reasons, framing is not allowed; click OK to remove the frames.")
    }
```